# Valid FirebaseIdToken for backend API call

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication in Android. I need to send `IdToken` to backend for every api call. What i did is given sequentially.

1. When app starts call [getIdToken(boolean forceRefresh)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-taskgettokenresult-getidtoken-boolean-forcerefresh) to get the token of user.
2. As i need the token later for api call i saved it locally
3. Register [FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/internal/IdTokenListener) to get new token when token is changed. As listener is called when token changed. Update local token.

But sometime my backed gives `401` for api call.
Here is my implementation

**Get token**

```
    firebaseUser.getIdToken(false)
            .addOnCompleteListener(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), OnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    setAccessToken(it.result?.token)
                } else {
                    setAccessToken(null)
                }
                removeIdTokenListener()
                registerForIdTokenListener()
            })
```

**Token change listener**

```
private val idTokenListener = IdTokenListener {
    val jwtToken = it.token
    if( jwtToken != null) {
        setAccessToken(jwtToken)           
    } else {
        setAccessToken(null)
    }
}


private fun registerForIdTokenListener() {
    mAuth.addIdTokenListener(idTokenListener)
}

private fun removeIdTokenListener(){
    mAuth.removeIdTokenListener(idTokenListener)
}
```

The problem i am facing is sometimes my backend gives `401` for invalid token.

What would be the right approach for sending token to server for every API call?

Some users in stackoverflow suggested to use `getIdToken` method in `Http` interceptor for every call. Is this good way to always call `getIdToken` for every api call?

Or only `IdTokenListener` listener register is enough to get always token update. Can i relay on this listener?

I have faced some issue using `IdTokenListener`. Sometime `IdTokenListener` is not triggered after register.

Help me to find out to do right thing for my app.

Comment: It is entirely unclear, why you'd even need to send the token to the backend ...because ordinary, one can obtain short-lived tokens on the server-side and send these to clients; exactly the other way around.

Comment: @MartinZeitler backed uses firebase authentication. As i work on app side don't know details